# Enforcing strict mode retroactively

Tags: javascript

I'd like to enforce function level strict mode (i.e. toggle [strict](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#strict) to true in the project's .jshintrc) on a legacy javascript project. Is there any way to do this aside from adding a "use strict"; line at the start of every single function in my project?

For any project (new or old) it seems like a lot of avoidable boilerplate. How do people (if at all) typically handle it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...aside from adding a "use strict"; line at the start of every single function in my project?

Yes, you can add it at the top of every file in the project (this is the "code compilation" level); it applies to all functions within the file (code compilation unit).

This is also true for inline script in web pages, FWIW, e.g.:

```
<script>
"use strict";
// This is strict mode code
function foo() {
    // So is this
}
</script>
<script>
// This isn't
</script>
```

Comment: It should be added that while this seems onerous it really isn't. A very simple command line script could do this for you and there is very little chance of breaking something since all you're doing is adding a line of text in a known location.

Comment: That's certainly less boilerplate than every function. The next question arises: is there a way to write "use strict"; only once (perhaps make some project architectural shift?) to apply strict mode to every file?

Comment: @calling: Probably not usefully, no. If you're combining scripts (and if not, why not?), you might be able to do it with your script combiner. But usually even when you use a script combiner, you don't use it when developing, so you want it in every file.